# Must declare the scalar variable, but its declared

Tags: sql, vb.net

I've declared a variable in the code, but I'm clueless on how its still showing the error, any ideas? 
 When I remove the `WHERE clauses` after it shows every row, but when putting them in I get `"Must declare the scalar variable @startdata"`.

```
connect()
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT h_initials, h_date, h_hours FROM [h_holidays] WHERE h_date >= @startdata AND h_date < @enddata "
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@startdata", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datetime_date.Value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@enddata", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datetime_2.Value
    cmd.ExecuteScalar()

    Dim dataAdapter_holidays_all = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con.ConnectionString)
    Dim table_holidays_all As New DataTable()
    table_holidays_all.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    dataAdapter_holidays_all.Fill(table_holidays_all)
    Me.bs_holidays_all.DataSource = table_holidays_all

    dgv_holidays_all.DataSource = bs_holidays_all

    disconnect()

    dgv_holidays_all.RowHeadersWidth = "28"

    dgv_holidays_all.Columns(0).HeaderText = "User:"
    dgv_holidays_all.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Date:"
    dgv_holidays_all.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Hours:"

    dgv_holidays_all.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False
```

I've tried .addwithvalue on the parameters with still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not declared.  Your code is rather all over the place.  You first create a `SqlCommand` object, add parameters to it and call its `ExecuteScalar` method, but that makes no sense because you are retrieving more than one value.  You then create a `SqlDataAdapter` with the same SQL but you don't add any parameters to its `SelectCommand`.

What you should be doing is creating a `SqlDataAdapter`, getting its `SelectCommand` and adding the parameters to it, e.g.

```
Dim sql = "SELECT h_initials, h_date, h_hours FROM [h_holidays] WHERE h_date >= @startdata AND h_date < @enddata"
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)

With adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters
    .Add("@startdata", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datetime_date.Value
    .Add("@enddata", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datetime_2.Value
End With
```

No additional `SqlCommand` object.  No pointless call to `ExecuteScalar`.